# Mobile push In-App messaging button behavior

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobilepush

I've sent an In-App message via a Journey where the button "A" has been assigned with the action "Open page in app".

Everything seems to work OK but I am not sure about the "**actionType**"

I am using the modal template.

```
{
    actionAndroid = "xxxx"; => OK
    actionIos = "xxxx"; => OK
    actionType = close; => ??? How could I set a different value here?
    backgroundColor = 0xFFFBFBF9; => OK
    borderColor = 0xFFC9C7C5; => OK
    fontColor = 0xFF706E6B; => OK
    id = "xxxx"; => OK
    index = 0; => OK
    text = "More details "; => OK
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select "URL" in the Marketing Cloud UI when creating the button for the message.